# Does "heroku local" provide HTTPS proxying?

Tags: heroku, reverse-proxy, heroku-cli

I've been playing around with a nodejs app on Heroku and got HTTPS setup pretty easily using Heroku's [Automated Certificate Management](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/automated-certificate-management), which manages the certificates and also [adds headers](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/http-routing#heroku-headers) to the incoming requests so I can see whether it came over HTTP or HTTPS.

I ran into some headaches developing locally as my local machine wasn't adding those headers and the logic to determine whether I was local was leaking throughout my app.  I ended up using node's *http-proxy* lib to wrap my app when running locally, which worked pretty well even adding the X headers my app was using.

```
if (IN_DEVELOPMENT) {
    const proxiedPort = 9090; // don't hit this directly
    startServer(proxiedPort);

    const httpProxy = require('http-proxy')

    httpProxy.createServer({
        target: {
            host: 'localhost',
            port: proxiedPort
        },
        ssl: {
            key: fs.readFileSync('./dummy/key.pem', 'utf8'),
            cert: fs.readFileSync('./dummy/cert.pem', 'utf8')
        },
        xfwd: true // add X-Forward-* headers as Heroku does
    }).listen(EXTERNAL_PORT);
} else {
   startServer(EXTERNAL_PORT);
}
```

After doing some more development I heard about the *heroku local* command that runs things locally and thought I was a complete idiot for wasting my time setting up the proxy, but after some testing it's just running my app using the *Procfile* and I still need to run this proxy locally.

Is there a workflow built-in to heroku CLI for handling the HTTPS proxy?

Comment: No, `heroku local` does not do that. Why do you want HTTPS locally?

Comment: It keeps the code more similar between the two environments.  For example, endpoints that need to be secure don't have to also check whether they're in development mode.

Comment: Endpoints shouldn't care about whether they're accessed over HTTPS or not. Enforce it elsewhere, e.g. application-wide as middleware. Redirect all HTTP request to HTTPS in production, and just use HTTP in development.